# What is a decent beginner graph puzzle?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I'm trying to get more acquainted with problems that require Graphs to be solved (are are best solved by graphs).

If someone has an old ACM Programming Competition problem that utilized graphs, or have another problem that they found particularly enlightening as they worked it out I would appreciate it.  I want to familiarize myself with graphs, identifying graph-type problems easily and be able to utilize basic graph traversal algorithmns.

Anyone have a sweet problem they can send my way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this book to be *extremely* useful (Amazon Link):
[Programming Challenges](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387001638)

Not only does it give a pretty indepth explanation of graphs, trees, basic data structures it gives a handful of programming challenges involving each type!  This document is more useful to me than my textbook!

Here are some of the Graph Problems in it:

Problems involving **Graph Traversal**:

- Bicoloring : pg 203
- Playing With Wheels : pg 204
- The Tourist Guide : pg 206
- Slash Maze : pg 208
- Edit Step Ladders : pg 210
- Tower of Cubes : pg 211
- From Dusk Till Dawn : pg 213
- Hanoi Tower Troubles (Again!) : pg 215

Problems involving **Graph Algorithms** (Dijkstra's, Min Spanning Tree, etc):

- Freckles : pg 231
- The Necklace : pg 231
- Fire Station : pg 234
- Railroads : pg 235
- War : pg 237
- The Grand Dinner : pg 241

Comment: Yes, but must mention that these tasks are from UVa online judge. Also there are such books as Competitive programming (https://sites.google.com/site/stevenhalim/) which are more new and in my opinion a bit better, but also really similar in structure to Programming Challanges.

Answer (score 2):

To get a better grasp of operations on graph, you might want to just implement some known [Graph algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory#Algorithms).

Try implementing a [Nurikabe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nurikabe) solver or generator. It would need quite a bit of classical graph operations.

Answer (score 1):

You should be familiar with the [Konigsberg Bridge Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Bridges_of_K%C3%B6nigsberg).  You should also get really familiar with the types of [data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory#Graph-theoretic_data_structures) that often come up in graph theory problems.

Answer (score 1):

Graphs can literally be used to model *almost* any problem. [Topcoder.com](http://topcoder.com) Marathon Matches often lend themselves to graph-based solutions.

- The [ProcessorScheduling](http://www.topcoder.com/longcontest/?module=ViewProblemStatement&rd=12166&pm=8708) problem could be solved with graphs.
- The [GraphBuilder](http://www.topcoder.com/longcontest/?module=ViewProblemStatement&rd=10128&pm=6858) problem.
- The [Distance](http://www.topcoder.com/longcontest/?module=ViewProblemStatement&rd=10681&pm=7297) problem.
- The [MapMaker](http://www.topcoder.com/longcontest/?module=ViewProblemStatement&rd=10123&pm=6733) problem (weighted k-coloring problem, which is a classic computer science problem).

You might checkout some of these problems - and there are more where they came from.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what language you are using (thinking of using).  If I may, I'd suggest Lisp or Python.  They're both good for easy graph manipulation.  If you want to be really fancy, you might want to create a pretty output using PyGame.

As for problem, have a look at a simple program and convert it into a graph.  Tip, each token is a node.  Assuming that you have some loops and equations, then you could traverse the graph and identify what could be moved outside of the loop.  Equations could be rearranged to be more "efficient".

My rationale for this problem is that it will help you as a programmer by seeing the sort of processes that might be going on inside the optimisation phases of a compiler.

BTW, if you give the above a go, have a look at [Plex](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/Plex/), it will save you a lot of time with parsers.

Answer (score 0):

http://codekata.pragprog.com/2007/01/kata_nineteen_w.html

Hint: a DAWG is a pretty good method.